# can't free qutoa using gcloud and Google Compete engine

Tags: gcloud

```
failed.
[INFO] ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: BACKEND_SERVICES (quota: 5, used: 5 + needed: 1).
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app command with exit code : 1
[INFO] --
```

---

i keep getting the above error when i try to deploy..I cannot delete my backend_services? 
i assume its `gcloud app instances list`
and simply delete the instances, however when I delete they just keep reinitialize. how can i free up the 5 instances using gcloud or the console.

i tried going to : https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?project=playchat-98e58 , but its not showing any instances?

```
$ gcloud.cmd app instances list
SERVICE  VERSION          ID                                VM_STATUS  DEBUG_MODE
default  20170317t203143  aef-default-20170317t203143-4ctc  RUNNING
default  20170317t203143  aef-default-20170317t203143-b4wr  RUNNING
default  20170317t203143  aef-default-20170317t203143-tpnt  RUNNING
default  20170317t205434  aef-default-20170317t205434-5fm7  RUNNING
default  20170317t205434  aef-default-20170317t205434-6rkt  RUNNING
default  20170317t205434  aef-default-20170317t205434-9nkq  RUNNING
default  20170317t212530  aef-default-20170317t212530-f869  RUNNING
default  20170317t212530  aef-default-20170317t212530-k6cn  RUNNING
default  20170317t212530  aef-default-20170317t212530-lszv  RUNNING
default  20170317t213906  aef-default-20170317t213906-5x7c  RUNNING
default  20170317t213906  aef-default-20170317t213906-8qg1  RUNNING
default  20170317t213906  aef-default-20170317t213906-qglb  RUNNING
default  20170318t002735  aef-default-20170318t002735-b60s  RUNNING
default  20170318t002735  aef-default-20170318t002735-hr4c  RUNNING
default  20170318t002735  aef-default-20170318t002735-wh80  RUNNING

twoen@DESKTOP-9R5VHUK MINGW64 ~/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin
$ gcloud.cmd compute backend-services list
Listed 0 items.
```

Comment: Try deleting deployed versions/services or adjusting the scaling settings–if you delete instances, App Engine will just autoscale right back up to the number you had before.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks,  could you make your 'comment' an answer...i was not able to do this via command line like it 'should' work i believe...but going to 'versions' and deleting 'App Engine Versions' resolved my quota issue:   i went to https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=foo-98e58&serviceId=default&versionId=20170317t213906

Answer (score 0):

[Backend services](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service) are resource that can exist independently from your deployed apps. You can try listing and deleting them:

```
gcloud compute backend-services list
gcloud compute backend-services delete $BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME
```